# Cordova Echo Plugin is returning false

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add Echo Plugin as per instrcution here

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android

Here are my changes

**config.xml**

```
<plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
```

**www/js/index.js**

```
    onDeviceReady : function() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

            window.echo = function(str, callback) {
cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
    callback('Nothing to echo.');
}, "org.apache.cordova.Echo", "echo", [str]);
```

};

**platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/Echo.java**

```
package org.apache.cordova;


import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */
public class Echo extends Plugin {
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)     throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("echo")) {
        String message = args.getString(0) ;
        this.echo(message, callbackContext);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
        callbackContext.success(message);
    } else {
        callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
    }
}
}
```

Command: **cordova build android && cordova emulate android**

Only when the application launch it shows a alert message "false"

Using 3.5.0-0.2.7

Thanks for Help on this

Answer (score 0):

Whomsoever is following, its far better idea to git clone an existing working plugin. In my case, i cloned cordova device plugin and add the few properties in Java and retrieved them in js file, like other properties. Afterwards, you can add the plugin with standard cordova command

**cordova plugin add < local_path_to_plugin>**

This way its easier to focus on information that needs to be passed from Native to Cordova, instead of trying, figuring the errors or plugin itself, unless definatly, your task is to understand the cordova plugins deeply.

Thanks